# How To Trade With CoinEx API?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

I'm Trying To Place A Market Order With CoinEx API But I Receive "Service Unavailable" Error !

API Documentation :

[API Invocation Description](https://github.com/coinexcom/coinex_exchange_api/wiki/012security_authorization)

[Acquire Market Statistics](https://github.com/coinexcom/coinex_exchange_api/wiki/021ticker)

[Place Market Order](https://github.com/coinexcom/coinex_exchange_api/wiki/032market_order)

Code :

```
<html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/md5.js"></script>
<script>
let AccessID="";//My Access ID
let Amount="";//Any Amount
let Market="";//Any Market
let Tonce=0;//MarketStatistics function
let Type="";//buy or sell
let SecretKey="";//My Secret Key

Process();
async function Process()
{
await MarketStatistics();
await MarketOrder(AccessID,Amount,Market,Tonce,Type,SecretKey);
}

async function MarketStatistics()
{
let MarketStatistics_Fetch=await fetch("https://api.coinex.com/v1/market/ticker/all");
let MarketStatistics_JSON=await MarketStatistics_Fetch.json();
let MarketStatistics_Data=await MarketStatistics_JSON.data;

Tonce=parseInt(MarketStatistics_Data.date);
}

async function MarketOrder(AccessID,Amount,Market,Tonce,Type,SecretKey)
{
let MarketOrder_Body={"access_id":AccessID,"amount":Amount,"market":Market,"tonce":Tonce,"type":Type};
let MarketOrder_Request="access_id="+AccessID+"&"+"amount="+Amount+"&"+"market="+Market+"&"+"tonce="+Tonce+"&"+"type="+Type;
let MarketOrder_Signature=CryptoJS.MD5(MarketOrder_Request+"&"+"secret_key="+SecretKey).toString().toUpperCase();

let MarketOrder_Fetch=await fetch("https://api.coinex.com/v1/order/market"+"?"+MarketOrder_Request,{method:"post",body:MarketOrder_Body,headers:{authorization:MarketOrder_Signature,"Content-Type":"application/json"}});
let MarketOrder_JSON=await MarketOrder_Fetch.json();

alert(MarketOrder_JSON.message);
}
</script>
</html>
```

Result : Service Unavailable

Comment: _"Service unavailable"_ indicates a problem on the server. There's (most likely) nothing you can do about that.

Answer (score 0):

check if you can get klines, if there is no problem with that, it means there is something wrong about your request like(signature,authorization,sort,...) and if klines api give your the same response as 'Service unavailable' this means there is something wrong with the server.
also check with VPN, mayble the service is unavailable in your country...